# Executing gcloud command `clusters get-credentials` in Bitbucket Pipeline is failing with --zone option

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines, google-cloud-shell

I am using the `gcloud clusters credentials`. When using it in the Cloud Shell it works fine. When using it in the *bitbucket-pipeline.yaml`however it fails on the`--zone` flag.

Used in Cloud Shell:

```
cloud container clusters get-credentials xetra11-cluster-dev --zone=europe-west3-a --project xetra11-project
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for xetra11-cluster-dev.
```

It executed fine as you can see.
So here is what I setup for the *bitbucket-pipeline.yaml*:

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:latest

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Build and push Docker image
          deployment: dev
          caches:
            - docker
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            # gcloud setup
            - echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE > ~/.gcloud-api-key.json
            - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ~/.gcloud-api-key.json
            - gcloud config set project xetra11-project
            - gcloud container clusters get-credentials xetra11-cluster --zone=europe-west3-a --project xetra11-project
            - gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet
```

The pipeline is failing on:

```
- gcloud container clusters get-credentials xetra11-cluster --zone=europe-west3-a --project xetra11-project
```

> - gcloud container clusters get-credentials $GCLOUD_CLUSTER --zone=$GCLOUD_ZONE --project $GCLOUD_PROJECT
>     ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) unrecognized arguments: europe-west3-a 
>     To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
>     gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

Can somebody tell me why this is happening? I am very sure I setup everything fine.

**EDIT**: @Pievis gave me a hint to use the setter for the zone. Unfortunately it also resulted in an error:

```
+ gcloud config set compute zone $GCLOUD_ZONE
ERROR: (gcloud.config.set) unrecognized arguments: europe-west3-a
```

Comment: Wow it is in fact a strange error, maybe you found a bug? which version of gcloud are you using ? Just as a work around, try to use gcloud config set compute zone europe-west3-a (this way you could get rid of the --zone flag in the later command)

Comment: @Pievis thx for the hint - will try it now

Comment: @Pievis also failed - see the edit in the question

Comment: Mm there might be something trivial we are missing, but it still seems like a bug to me, I think I would personally try the following to rule this out (if no ticket is already online): 1) try beta commands 2) try -z instead of --zone 3) try another gcloud version

Comment: Hi xetra11, the command to set the zone should be: `gcloud config set compute/zone $GCLOUD_ZONE` , with the slash between `compute` and `zone`. Could you please try this way?

Comment: this actually worked! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Putting variables in quotes helped to solve this error in my case.
I've realised bitbucket added some spaces at the start of the deployment variable.
Adding variable again solved the issue.